# What the meaning of various types of white space in Java?

Tags: java, string, spaces

What is difference of below escape sequences for white space?

\t, \n, \x0B, \f and \r.

Comment: What are you talking about? Those characters in the source code? In Strings? In String literals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you left out the operators, but I'm interpreting you to want to know how various Java APIs handle those characters.

The Java handling of these characters is determined by their Unicode character properties. See the Unicode spec to see what properties they have, and thus what the different functions in Character return for them.

www.unicode.org will tell you all you ever wanted to know about Unicode properties.

Comment: where i have to refer those stuff?

Comment: Since when is a tab, line feed, vertical tab, and carriage return a space?

Comment: @Steve Kuo, in the terminology of the questions, they were more spaces than operators. Point taken.

Answer (score 45):

- **`\t`**      The tab character (`\u0009`)
- **`\n`**      The newline (line feed) character (`\u000A`)
- **`\r`**      The carriage-return character (`\u000D`)
- **`\f`**      The form-feed character (`\u000C`)
- **`\x0B`**  The vertical tabulation (VT) character

Comment: \x0B is not space \x20 is the space.

Comment: @codaddict - you're right. It's the vertical tabulation character. Just edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
\t - Horizontal tab
\n - New line
\x0B - Vertical tab
\f - form feed
\r - carriage return
```